# How to detect when the control/notification center appears?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, notificationcenter, control-center

In my iOS app I want to know when the control or the notification center appears. Is there a notification specifically for this available? The notifications for `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` do not help in my situation because they are not specific enough.

Comment: No there is not notification available to detect if the user opens the control/notification center. You only indication is the `applicationWillResignActive`.

Comment: @rckoenes thanks for the info. Do you know if it is possible to detect if the control/notification center is open. Then I could test for it in `applicationWillResignActive`.

Comment: No this is not possible.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29144992/470964